# Can't install Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I just opened a fresh project in angular CLI and I wanted to install Material with:

> npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

But it gave me the following errors:

```
C:\Users\TijlD\Desktop\projects\untitled46>npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk 
npm WARN @angular/animations@5.2.8 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.2.8 but none was installed. 
npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none was installed. 
npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none was installed. 
npm WARN @angular/material@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none was installed. 
npm WARN @angular/material@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none was installed.
```

Does anyone know what this means and how to get rid of it?

**Edit: when I check the Angular version**

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 9.3.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.8
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: what's your angular version?

Comment: I added the result of ng --version to the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NPM is telling you that Angular Material requires Angular 5.2 or a newer version. Probably you are using Angular 4 or lower.

Angular Material does not install Angular, it requires you to install it (the same way Angular requires you to have RxJS).

Check your package.json to see what version of Angular you have.

Also, update your global angular-cli package, probably you've got an older one.

You can check with `ng --version`, and can update it with `npm update -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

you try to install last version of angular material that not support angular 5.2
please update your angular version or try to install lower version of angular material